# How to add the grad method to a theano Op?

Tags: python, theano

I have create a `theano.Op` that returns distance between each pair of the two collections of inputs, converting the `scipy` `cdist`:

```
class Cdist(theano.Op):

    __props__ = ()

    def __init__(self):
        #self.fn = scipy_cdist2
        super(Cdist, self).__init__()

    def make_node(self, x, w):
        #print('make_node')
        return gof.Apply(self, [x, w], [x.type()])

    def perform(self, node, inputs, output_storage):
        #print('perform')
        x, w = inputs[0], inputs[1]
        z = output_storage[0]
        z[0] = distance.cdist(x, w, 'euclidean')
```

It works, but now want to add the grad method. I have read the [guide](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/extending/extending_theano.html) and the [documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/extending/op.html) about the `grad` method. But i still dont't understand how it works. For example in the [guide](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/extending/extending_theano.html) to get the gradient of a method that return `a*x + b`, they use:

```
def grad(self, inputs, output_grads):
    return [a * output_grads[0] + b]
```

why? I'm going to quote what is written in the [documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/extending/op.html) about the `grad`:

> If the output list of the op is [f_1, ... f_n], then the list
>   output_gradients is [grad_{f_1}(C), grad_{f_2}(C), ... ,
>   grad_{f_n}(C)]. If inputs consists of the list [x_1, ..., x_m], then
>   Op.grad should return the list [grad_{x_1}(C), grad_{x_2}(C), ...,
>   grad_{x_m}(C)], where (grad_{y}(Z))_i = \frac{\partial Z}{\partial
>   y_i} (and i can stand for multiple dimensions).

They are told me that i have to write the gradient? But in the example the make a combination of `output_grads` and integger values. Really i'm not understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong about docs. In `grad` method you should write a *symbolic* expression, as opposed to `perform` method where you write a *numerical* expression.

`grad` method is called from `theano.grad`, while `perform` is called inside the compiled function.

For example, assuming euclidean distance:

```
def grad(self, inputs, out_grads):
    x, y = inputs   # matrices of shape [mA, n] and [mB, n]]
    g, = out_grads   # matrix of shape [mA, mB]
    diff = x.dimshuffle(0, 'x', 1) - y.dimshuffle('x', 0, 1)   # [mA, mB, n] tensor
    z = T.sqrt(T.sum(T.sqr(diff), axis=2, keepdims=True))
    diff = g * diff / z
    return [T.sum(diff, axis=1), -T.sum(diff, axis=0)]
```

For this particular case, I'd suggest writing a `L_op` instead of `grad`. `L_op` additionally reuses output in the forward Op.

```
def L_op(self, inputs, outputs, out_grads):
    x, y = inputs   # matrices of shape [mA, n] and [mB, n]
    z, = outputs   # matrix of shape [mA, mB]
    g, = out_grads   # idem
    diff = x.dimshuffle(0, 'x', 1) - y.dimshuffle('x', 0, 1)   # [mA, mB, n] tensor
    diff = g.dimshuffle(0, 1, 'x') * diff / z.dimshuffle(0, 1, 'x')
    return [T.sum(diff, axis=1), -T.sum(diff, axis=0)]
```

Well, the grad expressions are probably wrong but you get the idea.

As you can see, we are calling symbolic functions such as `dimshuffle`. However there are cases where you want to write a class for grad Op. Either because the symbolic graph is too inefficient or you want a custom gradient.

For example:

```
class CDistGrad(theano.Op):
    def __init__(...):
        # <...>
        pass
    def c_code(...):
        # implement this in case you want more performance
        pass
    def perform(...):
        # <...>
        pass
    def make_node(...):
        # <...>
        pass

class CDist(theano.Op):
    # <...>
    def grad(self, inputs, output_grads):
        return CDistGrad()(*inputs, *output_grads)
```

Still, symbolic expression is used in `grad` method. Just a custom Op replaced vanilla Theano expression.